# Run script on two machines

Tags: linux, shell

I have a shell script that I need to automate with cron. At our office, there is a specific machine that I must log in to in order to use cron. My problem is, that the script I have written interacts with git, using git commands to pull code and switch branches. The machine where I am able to schedule cron jobs and the script is being run from does **not** have git on it. I have a separate machine that I log in to when I am using git. Is there an easy way for me to run my script from the cron system and run the git part from the git system?

UPDATE: I am still interested if this can be done, but my team has acquired a new machine that we will set up however we choose, meaning that it will have cron and git. Thanks for any ideas

Comment: Sounds like you need to have a word with the people maintaining your systems - either install git on the machine that can do cron, or set up cron on the other machine. Yes, we can make life complicated by trying to solve the problem another way, but that seems a little like the Swedish saying "to cross the river to fetch water".

Comment: You do not need to be root to install git and use it. Just download the source code and install it in your home directory by using the appropriate install prefix. Or get a statically linked version and just place it in your home directory.

Comment: @MatsPetersson haha I am not happy with the way our systems are set up, it has been a source of much frustration for me lately. Thanks for the tips

Comment: @er0 That solution would work, but it is pretty ugly and then it does not benefit my entire team. If it comes to that, then that is what I may end up doing.

Comment: You could use ssh to run the command remotely. But shouldn't you ask on Unix.SE if this is still a question you have?

Comment: @derobert I'm sorry, I posted in the channel with which I am most familiar and have had the most success. Like I mentioned in my edited post though, my team has resolved the issue with a different solution. Now it is just personal curiosity.

Comment: Well, you can't run software on one machine, from another machine, without some sort of root access in one way or another, because you either need to mount filesystems, install software or something else like that. So unless you have access to do that, then it's not possible [assuming security is reasonable on the system in the first place, and I guess you wouldn't be asking if that wasn't the case]. You can of course set off a `cron` job that uses `ssh` to do things on another machine, but then you may just as well run `cron` on that machine in the first place...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As some people have mentioned above, **ssh** is the way to do this. This is a bash line that I use a lot in my job, for gathering data from other servers:

```
ssh -T $server -l username "/export/home/path/to/script.sh $1  $2" 1>traf1.txt 2>/dev/null
```

The above code sample will connect to the ip $server, as user *username* and run the script *script.sh*, passing it the parameters $1 and $2. Instead of redirection you could also assign the command output to a variable, just as you would with any other command in your script.

PS: Please note that in order for the above to work, you will need to set up [passwordless login](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/152) between those machines. Otherwise your script will break to request password input, which is most probably not the desired behavior.